# mongodb - filter collection by string array contains ""

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For the below document, I want to write mongodb query to get the result.

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "class": "class1",
        "value": "xyz"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "class": "class2",
        "value": "abc"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "class": "class3",
        "value": "123"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "class": "class4"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "class": "class5",
        "value": ""
    }
]
```

The search parameter is an array of values - ["abc", "xyz", ""] and this is
going to look attribute "value"
The output should be below and in this case, the third item in the search array "" is pointing to collection that has "id" - 4 and 5 :

```
[{
        "id": "1",
        "class": "class1",
        "value": "xyz"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "class": "class2",
        "value": "abc"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "class": "class4"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "class": "class5",
        "value": ""
    }
]
```

Please assist to provide the mongodb query to get the result like this

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have blank string you can add `null` in array, like this,

```
db.collection.find({
  value: {
    $in: ["abc", "xyz", "", null]
  }
})
```